# Python Class Variable from dict comprehension referencing subclass

Tags: python, class, scope, dictionary-comprehension

Consider this code

```py
class A:
    class B:
        foo = 1
    bar = {x: B for x in range(5)}
```

This will produce an error saying that `B` is not defined. However, when stopping with the debugger at the corresponding line, on the REPL, I can run that code just fine. This appears to be some nesting / scoping problem, but I don't understand it.

Can someone explain what's going on and maybe how to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dict comprehension implicitly defines an anonymous function. Within the body of that function, `B` is a free variable. The variable lookup rules state that the value of `B` is taken from the closest enclosing scope that defines `B`, *but* a `class` statement doesn't define a scope (though it does define a temporary namespace that is similar to a proper scope). The next scope up from the anonymous function's local scope is the global scope, where `B` is not defined.

To avoid the binding issue, define a function which takes `B` as an argument, and have that function execute the dict comprehension:

```
bar = (lambda cls: {x: cls for x in range(5)})(B)
```

Now, `B` is can be found in the current namespace of the `class` statement (scoping rules are avoided), and `cls`, being defined in the scope of the anonymous function defined by the lambda expression, can now be found in the stack of scopes used by the dict comprehension. Put another way, the anonymous function created by the comprehension is a closure over the scope of the lambda expression's function.

That said, nested classes aren't really common in Python; you could define `B` at the global scope to solve the problem in this case.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The slight indentation in the original doesn't help.